# If plants convert a greenhouse gas into a non-greenhouse gas, do they cool?

Tags: climate-change

Plants turn Carbon Dioxide into Oxygen, that is not a greenhouse gas. But Carbon Dioxide is.

Therefore, wouldn't plants cool the area?

Comment: The issue is not that they *turn carbon dioxide into oxygen*, it's that they store the carbon in the plant. With lots of trees, you make a carbon *sink*, reducing the amount of carbon in the atmosphere, slowing climate change (warming). There's tons of research of the effect(iveness) of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plants are natural machines that convert $CO_{2}$ into $O_{2}$ when there is sunlight. This process is known as photosynthesis because photons provide the energy that triggers the reaction,
$$6CO_{2} + 6H_{2}O -> C_{6}H_{12}O_{6} + 6O_{2}$$

The question then is where do the plant products,such as leaves, fruits, flowers,roots that are composed of $C_{6}H_{12}O_{6}$  stored? If these plant remains are stored in the ground more than they are decomposed and then release $CO_{2}$ into the atmosphere, then we can positively say they are the natural cleaning robots, sorry super-robots or cleaning freaks!

Comment: I don't understand what you said. I'm just going to accept this answer and move on

Comment: Ask as much question as you like.

Comment: You will understand soon. Start with the basic ones. Ask your father or teacher and step by step, you will reach the level of understanding that you want.

Comment: "then we can positively say they are the natural cleaning robots, sorry super-robots or cleaning freaks!" the question was about cooling, not cleaning.

Comment: Cleaning CO2 from the atmosphere leads to reduction in temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Plants do cool the area around them but it is not due to gas exchange, (not directly) plants provide shade and loss water during gas exchange this loss creates evaporative cooling. oxygen and carbon dioxide diffuse too quickly to much effect on the local environment where they are produced by themselves.

Comment: Also, the warming produced by CO2 is a long-term, global process.  It doesn't selectively affect the local area of the plants.